# Error: Actions must be plain objects BUT I can't see the issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, redux-thunk

I'm calling an action from one of my components, and have tried to refactor the action so that I'm not writing loads of redundant code. However, whenever I pass more than one argument to the action (or even if I pass a single argument but as an array or object) I get the 'actions must be plain objects' error. I am using Redux Thunk, but what's baffling about this is that the async function is abstracted away, so there shouldn't be a problem.

First here's what **does** work:

Here's the dispatch call in the component

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(fetchExposure(fundIds[value]))
```

And here's the action:

```
export const fetchExposure = fundName =>
  getIndividualFundData(
    SERVER_URL + `fund_gem_data/${fundName}`,
    fundName,
    "exposure"
  );
```

and getIndividualFundData looks like this:

```
function getIndividualFundData(
  url,
  data,
  area
) {
  console.log("getind called")
  console.log(url, data, area)
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchBegin(data, "FETCH_INDIVIDUAL_FUND_BEGIN", area));
    return fetch(url)
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(fetchSuccess(json, data, "FETCH_INDIVIDUAL_FUND_SUCCESS", area));
        return json;
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchFailure(error, data, "FETCH_INDIVIDUAL_FUND_FAILURE", area)));
  };
}
```

This all works just fine.

Now for what **doesn't work.** What I want to do is pass the json url (the 'fund_gem_data' bit) in with the action, as well as the store area ('exposure') to make the action reusable for other parts of the store.

So here's the action I wrote:

```
export const fetchData = data => {
   const [fundName, jsonPrefix, storeArea] = data;
   console.log(fundName, jsonPrefix, storeArea)

    getIndividualFundData(
        SERVER_URL + `${jsonPrefix}/${fundName}`,
        fundName,
        storeArea
    );
}
```

and then I call this in the component:

```
if (props.funds.funds.length) {
        let data = [ props.funds.funds[0].data[0][0], 
            "fund_gem_data", 
            "exposure"
            ]
      dispatch(fetchData(data));

    // dispatch(fetchExposure(props.funds.funds[0].data[0][0]))
    }
```

However, this instantly throws the error, even though I can't see a single thing wrong with the code. I've tried passing through an object too, and that doesn't work.

From the reducer point of view (and from the getIndividualFundData function point of view) there is absolutely *no difference* between these. Yet redux won't allow me to do it.

So my question is, why can the function that I pass to useDispatch() only take a single string as a parameter? Why not an object or an array?

If anyone could clarify this for me I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - I wasn't returning the function in the action, hence the issue...